# Difference between "echo 'hello'; ls" vs "echo 'hello' && ls"?

Tags: bash

I wonder what the difference between

```
"echo 'hello'; ls"
```

and

```
"echo 'hello' && ls"
```

is? they both do the same thing

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/334994/which-one-is-better-using-or-to-execute-multiple-commands-in-one-line

Answer (score 22, accepted):

"echo 'hello' && ls" means : execute "ls" if "echo 'hello'" runs successfully. To understand what is "successful" in bash. Try this :

bash> cd /
bash> echo $?

if the previous command runs successfully, you should see 0

After that, try this :

bash> asdfdf
bash> echo $?

You should see a non-zero value between 1 and 255. This means previous command didn't run successfully

On the other hand, "echo 'hello'; ls" means execute "ls" whether "echo 'hello'" runs successfully or not.

Comment: No, *no*, **no** it will *not* be a random value. It's a very *specific* value. It's a "command not found" error and `echo $?` will give you 127 in Bash, zsh, ksh, dash and ash and probably others. Other values will be *specific* to the type of error (but they may vary in some cases from one shell to another). The value is *never*, *ever* **random**.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. It's indeed exit status of previous command and it is never random. I wonder where the exit status list is documented. Hmmm..

Comment: I believe they're generally documented in the man pages of the individual commands, with the bash man page giving some general advice. Check out the 'EXIT STATUS' section of `man bash`.

Answer (score 16):

The `&&` is the logical AND operator. The idea in its use in `command1 && command2` is that command2 is only evaluated/run if command1 was successful. So here `ls` will only be run if the `echo` command returned successful (which will always be the case here, but you never know ;-). You could also write this as:

```
if echo 'hello'
then
  ls
fi
```

The semicolon just delimits two commands. So you could also write `echo 'hello' ; ls` as:

```
echo 'hello'
ls
```

Thus `ls` will also be executed even when `echo` fails.

BTW, successful in this context means that the program was exited with something like `exit(0)` and thus returned 0 as a return code (the `$?` shell variable tells you the return status of the last executed command).

Answer (score 8):

To supplement [DarkDust's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573742/difference-between-echo-hello-ls-vs-echo-hello-ls/3573817#3573817):

> So here ls will only be run if the echo command returned successful (which will always be the case here, but you never know ;-).

Well, not always.  For example, the standard output stream may be unwritable

```
:; ( echo "foo" && touch /tmp/succeeded) >/dev/full
bash: echo: write error: No space left on device
:; ls -l /tmp/succeeded
ls: cannot access /tmp/succeeded: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4):

Here, they do the same.

But take an other example:

```
cp file target && ls
cp file target; ls
```

In the first case, `ls` would only be executed if `cp` succeeds.
In the second case, no matter if `cp` fails or succeeds, `ls` will always be executed.

Comment: As DarkDust and telent mention, echo can indeed fail, although it's usually not something the script would care about or test for.